# Validation problems on manual update of attribute value in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple problem. I want to change some field value for my `User.find(1)` in rails console.

I tried:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.update_attributes(roles_mask: 3)
```

And got `false` returned. When I check `u.errors.full_messages`, I see that it's because there is a problem with password validation from `has_secure_password`. How can I update it manually in the console?

Comment: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute

Answer (score 72, accepted):

if you want to bypass validation, use

```
# skip validations but run callbacks
u.update_attribute :roles_mask, 3
```

or

```
# do the update on the sql so no validation and callback is executed
u.update_column :roles_mask, 3
```

Comment: For completeness sake, in Rails 4 you can use `u.update_attributes(roles_mask: 3, password: 'password')` but you need to know the password to set multiple params at once.

Answer (score 11):

You have to authenticate the user first then you can update the user have a look [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password)

```
u = User.find(1)
u.authenticate("password")
u.update_attributes(roles_mask: 3)
```

Or if you want to skip the validations you can do as follow;

```
u = User.find(1)
u.update_attribute :roles_mask, 3
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try `update_attribute(:roles_mask, 3)` or `update_column(:roles_mask, 3)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can have something like this

```
Post.find(1).comments.first.update(body: "hello")
```

or

```
@u = Post.find(1)
@u.comments.first.update(body: "hello")
```

where comments is the name of the comment table, body is the name of column in the comment table.

This applies when you have nested attribute

post.rb

```
has_many: comments
accept_nested_attributes_for: comment
```

comment.rb

```
belongs_to: post
```